# How to make a word cloud from CSV file using Python

Tags: python, csv, word-cloud

I have the following CSV file:

```
    Emoji,CNT,Common
    369,3988,yes
    sosad,2820,yes
    agree,1481,no
    clown,1273,yes
    dead,753,yes
    angry,561,no
    good,404,yes
    agger/dead,317,no
    cry,305,yes
    smile,300,yes
```

When I searched related information, they have only 1 column. However, I have a CSV file that must make a word cloud picture. What is more, I need to use the above file to make more information. If the "Common" column is "yes",  it will show red color. Otherwise, it will show black color.

I searched a lot of information. They have only 1 column. And then they have only 1 color or random colors.

Therefore, I cannot make my respect result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add to the previous answer, this is an example code that will do what you asked for using the wordcloud library. You will need to split the CSV into two dictionaries, one for the main data and another one for the colors.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from wordcloud import WordCloud

# Load data as pandas dataframe
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file_location)

# Create dictionaries out of the dataframe
records = df.to_dict(orient='records')
data = {x['Emoji']: x['CNT'] for x in records}
colors = {x['Emoji']: x['Common'] for x in records}

# Generate word cloud from frequencies
wc = WordCloud(background_color="white", max_words=1000)
wc.generate_from_frequencies(data)

# Color words depending on the colors dictionary
def color_func(word, **kwargs):
    if colors.get(word) == 'yes':
        return "rgb(0, 255, 0)"
    else:
        return "rgb(255, 0, 0)"

wc.recolor(color_func=color_func)

# Show final result
plt.imshow(wc, interpolation="bilinear")
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

This will give you a picture looking like this:

[image: Word cloud]

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to read this csv file correctly, You can do that simply with python's pandas library as follow:[Reading csv file in python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgKBu.png)

Then you can use python's wordcloud library by installing it as

pip install wordcloud

for some nice example of wordcloud follow https://github.com/amueller/word_cloud#examples